# Gitlab Failed to get username: Internal API unreachable

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-push, git-clone

for long time i have a private gitlab.
But now i transfert my gitlab to a domain name with ssl certificate.
Since i make this, i have this error when i tried to clone a repository.
I make some checks, I'm correctly logged

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

But I get a

```
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote: 
remote: Failed to get username: Internal API unreachable
remote: 
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
```

Can someone help me to understand what is it ? and why i have this error.

Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: Just had the same error, in my case I forgot to adjust the config.yml of gitlab-shell.

maybe also check gitlab, based on your installation method `gitlab-rake gitlab:check` or `bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`  
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/raketasks/maintenance.html#check-gitlab-configuration